# How to calculate the mean in a data frame using aggregate function in R?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data frame df1:

```
number=c(4,3,2,3,4,1)
year=c("2000","2000","2000", "2015", "2015", "2015")
items=c(12, 10, 15, 5, 10, 7)
df1=data.frame(number, year, items)
setDT(df1)[, Prop := number/sum(number), by = year]
```

such that it looks like this:

```
  number year items      Prop
1:      4 2000    12 0.4444444
2:      3 2000    10 0.3333333
3:      2 2000    15 0.2222222
4:      3 2015     5 0.3750000
5:      4 2015    10 0.5000000
6:      1 2015     7 0.1250000
```

I want to get the mean of the number of items per year, so I tried using this fuction:

```
mean.df1=aggregate((df1$number*df1$Prop),list(df1$year), mean)
```

but it returns the wrong values for the mean. I want it to return:

```
  Group.1        x
1    2000 2.918918
2    2015 2.296296
```

where Group.1 is the year and x is the correct mean.

Thanks!

Comment: Just `df1[, mean(number*Prop), by = year]`? Why are using `aggregate` here in the first place? Does the `aggregate` syntax make more sense to you than some simple key strokes with `data.table`?

Comment: How did you get those results? How is the average number of items per year 2.918918 for 2000??

Comment: Consider matching your desired output to the data given to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 8):

To `aggregate` mean number of items/year

```
aggregate(number ~ year, data=df1, mean)
#   year   number
# 1 2000 3.000000
# 2 2015 2.666667
```

#### Edit

For the weighted average in base R you could do standard split-apply-combine

```
sapply(split(df1, df1$year), function(x) weighted.mean(x$number, w=x$items))
```

or

```
sapply(split(df1, df1$year), function(x) sum(x$number*x$items)/sum(x$items))
#     2000     2015 
# 2.918919 2.818182
```

Comment: Doesn't get intended output\

Comment: @SeñorO the desired output does not match the given input.

Comment: You don't really have to use a formula. OPs approach will give identical result to yours with `aggregate(df1$number,list(df1$year), mean)`

Comment: But how "readable" answers the question? OP provided a working code that he claims that doesn't work, while you provide the same solution with a more readable code. How is that a solution?

Comment: Your solution doesn't take in count the proportion part (weighted mean) which is crucial to the OP it seems. So this will be even worse solution probably

Answer (score 3):

How about using the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df1  %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(mean = sum(number * items)/sum(items))
```

which gives

```
  year     mean
1 2000 2.918919
2 2015 2.818182
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had to switch "mean" to "sum" in my aggregate function such that it becomes:

```
mean.df1=aggregate((df1$number*df1$Prop),list(df1$year), sum)
```

Comment: Again, you have a `data.table` object. Why are you using `aggregate`? Why not just `df1[, sum(number*Prop), by = year]`?